# Child Not Inheriting Some of the Properties/Behavior Of Its Parent?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I extended a class and added 1 property, with getters and setters, to the child.

Now I see in the debugger that this new child class is not picking up some of the properties of its parent.

Meaning: When I was using the parent, these properties were coming through, but with the child, they are nulls/0s. However, not all properties are nulled.

What I am curious about - by extending the original class, should not all of the original behavior be inherited in the new child class?

Some code samples:

```
public class ParentLensRequest extends AbstractLensRequest implements [long list of classes] {
    private Map<String, Interval> intervals = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public Set<Interval> getPeriods() {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.intervals)) {
            this.intervals = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        }
        return intervals.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    }
    @Override
    public void addInterval(Interval interval) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(interval, "Interval is required");
        this.intervals.put(interval.getName(), interval);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateInterval(String name, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, Optional<String> nameWithDates,
            Optional<String> longName) {
        //more code
    }
}
```

Child:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ChildLensRequest extends ParentLensRequest {
  private ContextObject context;
}
```

No constructor on the parent and any setters should be inherited. What am I missing?

Comment: Unrelated:  Your getPeriods method can be reduced to the single line, `return new LinkedHashSet<>(intervals.values());`.

Answer (score 1):

The only property that `ParentLensRequest` has is `intervals`, which is `private`. Although `ChildLensRequest` instances do have an `intervals` field (because an instance of `ChildLensRequest` is an instance of `ParentLensRequest`), code in `ChildLensRequest` cannot see it, because it's `private`. (Code in `ParentLensRequest` can see it on the child instance, but not code in the code class.)

If you intend the child class to be able to interact with `intervals` in its own code, give it a broader access level (like `protected`).

Comment: I should clarify. There are getters, setters, update methods etc for this property which are public. I will add them to the code sample.

Comment: @8t12c7081 - Then they are accessible on child instances, from child code (or any other code, since they're `public`). What makes you think they aren't?

Comment: As @Crowder said, if you have getters and setters for the private variable then it should be accessible on the child. _"Private variables cannot be used/accessed in child class. But if you want to use them, either you can use it through getters/setters or by making the variable protected (it means you can access the variables in a same package)"_

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the question isn't why aren't the accessible - the question is why would the field not be populated. These methods are all there, however the behavior of the class changes after I extend from it in that these fields are now null. I'm trying to understand why this might be.

Comment: @8t12c7081 - You'll need to update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Fundamentally, fields are null because nothing has ever written a non-null value to them. `intervals` definitely doesn't have that problem (unless something is assigning `null` to it in code you haven't shown), as it's initialized by the `ParentLensRequest` constructor (that's where instance initializers are relocated to during compilation).